# How To Get Focus In The Address Bar On Opening Chrome Browser (so you can start typing in the address bar right away)?

Tags: google-chrome, focus

All I am trying to do is to be able to click on Chrome executable and have it opened with the focus in the address bar?

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Is there a parameter that I can supply with "chrome.exe \some parameter" that will do it?

When I developed an app that used Awesomium which is based on Chromium - I could do it all. But Google Chrome is a commercial closed source product so we just get to see what we get to see so to speak.

PS: Appreciate the downvote, folks - still love ya all! I do try my best searching for the answer before I search for it here on stackoverflow though.